# not able to click a button in www::mechanize perl

Tags: perl, mechanize

after i filled a certain form, im trying to click this button

```
<input class="proceed" type="button" name="new_proceed" value="Create">
```

, when i tried

```
$mech->click_button(name=>"new_proceed");
```

it gives me an error telling me there's no clickable object with this name. and when used

```
$mech->click_button(value=>"Create");
```

i get can't call method "header" on an undefined value at `C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm line 2467.`

So whats wrong? Thanks

Comment: sry this is the html code for the button <input class="proceed" type="button" name="new_proceed" value="Create">

Comment: Posting some code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<input class="proceed" type="button" name="new_proceed" value="Create">`

Since it is of type `button`, it doesn't do anything in HTML (it is usually used as something to bind JavaScript to, which WWW::Mechanize doesn't support).

Look to something that supports JS such as [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox/) instead.

Comment: Just to clarify, in order for it to submit a form without JavaScript, it had to have had `type="submit"`

Answer (score 0):

Try $mech->click_button(name=>"new_proceed");

Answer (score 0):

try using HTML::Forms.. U can get the form info from the view source and you can click the button .. Another option is $mech->request .. u can create a request using make_request once u r done with filling up the form and then use $mech->request